# Use prop_search, per UIList Item?

Tags: objects

I am wondering if it's possible, to add a prop_search per Item in a UIList?

I'm trying to create a item/row, where it has like, 2 Labels, then the prop_search element at the far right.   So basically the row would read like:

index:0   "text"   prop_search

I would ideally want to do it, per Row/Item in the List, as I have.
So the user could click the dropdown/search, and choose a Mesh/Object per entry.

By default I'd like to have the prop_search populated with a specific object in the scene, but let the user change the object in the prop_search if they choose so, and I use that / change other things based on that.

I'm trying to create a condensed Boolean Popup Dialog/List, and let the user change the Bool Objects there / Operator Mode, and do some other things.

[image]

Right now as I change 1 dropdown, they all change.  Also they are not getting the specific object I want to use/set in there.

Seems like I'd need to maybe make a pointerProperty per item, or add entry to pointerProperty Array, if is a thing that exists?

I'm very new to Python/Blender, so have alot to learn.

Any ideas?

Thank you!!!

Edit:

So I found out that doing something like this, almost works.  I can load in my Objects, choose another one, but it then RENAMES the original object with the chosen one....

I was able to use a regular layout.prop, but then I can't get the search/dropdown to select another object.  But I can rename OK.

Maybe since I'm supplying object,"name", it's updating the current one, instead of replacing...

```
split.prop_search(obj,"name",bpy.context.scene,"objects","","",False,'OBJECT_DATA')
```

Comment: I got it working now, but without the eyeDropper.   I think i need to use the PointerProperty and with a collection or something maybe?   Is is possible to set an initial object selected , then search / pick only meshes ?